# Cell data not showing up in UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, alamofire

Any idea how i can be making this GET request with Alamofire - getting exactly what I want back - passing the info to the func tableView(tableView: UITableView - populating and returning each cell and yet my table, simply, will not show the loaded data?

From within the AlamoFire promised return i call self.refresh() which calls this in the main thread:

```
func refresh() {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        });
```

--
Any ideas? This is literally driving me nuts.  Thanks for any ideas or solutions in advance!

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import MapKit

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tools = [Tool]()


    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLat: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
    var currentLong: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 116
        self.tableView.registerClass(ToolTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ToolTableViewCell")

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

//        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        //        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
        currentLat = location.coordinate.latitude
        currentLong = location.coordinate.longitude

    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
        tools = []

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let userid: Int = defaults.objectForKey("toolBeltUserID") as! Int

        let searchTerm = String(searchBar.text!)
        print(searchTerm)


        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:3000/tools/search", parameters: ["keyword": searchTerm, "latitude": currentLat, "longitude": currentLong,
            "user": userid]) .responseJSON {response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("\(JSON)")

                    for i in 0 ..< JSON.count {

                        let owner = JSON[i].objectForKey("owner")
                        let tool = JSON[i].objectForKey("tool")
                        let title = tool!["title"] as! String!
                        let ownerId = owner!["id"] as! Int!
                        let distanceToTool = JSON[i].objectForKey("distance") as! Double
                        var description: String

                        if let des = tool!["description"] as?  NSNull {
                            description = ""
                        } else {
                            description = (tool!["description"] as? String!)!
                        }

                        let myTool = Tool(title: title!, description: description, ownerId: ownerId!, distance: distanceToTool)


                        self.tools.append(myTool)

                    }

//                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        self.refresh()

//                    })

                } else {
                    print("Sent search term, but no response")
                }
        }

    }

    func refresh() {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        });

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(tools.count)
        return tools.count
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellIdentifier = "ToolTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as!ToolTableViewCell
        let tool = tools[indexPath.row]

        if(indexPath.row==0){
        cell.title?.text = tool.title
        //       print(tool.title)
        //        cell.toolListDescription?.text = tool.description
        cell.ownerId = tool.ownerId
        //        print(tool.ownerId)
        //       print(tool.distance)
        //        cell.distance?.text = "\(tool.distance)mi"
        }

        print(cell)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?  is `numberOfRowsInSection` being called?  is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called?  Is your tableview on screen (e.g. constraints set properly)?

Comment: Yes and Yes that is what is so confusing. With regard to proper constraints - how do I make sure of this on the storyboard?

Comment: The first thing I normally do is set the background color to bright green or something so you can see if the tableview is visible. Check for orange or red constraints warnings in the storyboard.  Also check that your `cell.title` property isn't nil - set a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and check

Comment: (lldb) po cell.title.text
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Comment: might this indicate that the label isn't properly getting assigned?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `cell.title` is nil - check your @IBOutlet is assigned in your custom cell class if that is how you are doing it - I notice you are registering the cell class for the reuse identifier - you shouldn't do this if you are using a storyboard prototype cell

Comment: The label is assigned properly in the custom cell class - what should I register as the reuse identifier ?

Comment: If you simply add the reuse identifier to the cell in the storyboard then the reuse identifier is registered for you.  No need to register anything in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I think i originally set that in response to this SIGABRT warning:

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ToolTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Double check your cell prototype in the storyboard.  Its reuse identifier isn't set to `ToolTableViewCell`

Comment: identifier is blank and I removed the 'register class' like from viewDidLoad() - it doesn't like me

Comment: Reuse Identifier can't be blank.  It must be `ToolTableViewCell`

Comment: Paul - you are a gentleman and a scholar

Comment: this held me up for like 2 days

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set the `Reuse Identifier` in the `attribute inspector!`  in my case it was `'ToolTableViewCell'`

Thanks!